# Haskell Tic-Tac-Toe (with automation and GUI)

Tags: haskell, tic-tac-toe, gui, state-machine, state

There are already many Tic Tac Toe posts. But as far as I can tell, none of the ones in Haskell are complete with a GUI

Here is my implementation with Gloss. [Gist Link for convenience](https://gist.github.com/Agnishom/4f2bdcbedbb3714e847ee2d17810ccf6)

```hs
module Board where

import Data.Map (Map, (!))
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.List (intercalate)

data Player = X | O
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

newtype Board = Board (Map (Int, Int) (Maybe Player))
    deriving (Eq, Ord)

initBoard :: Board
initBoard = Board $ Map.fromList [((x, y), Nothing) | x <- [0..2], y <- [0..2]]

getMark :: Board -> (Int, Int) -> Maybe Player
getMark (Board board) (x, y)
    | x < 0 || x > 2 || y < 0 || y > 2 = error "Invalid coordinates"
    | otherwise = board ! (x, y)

putMark :: Board -> Player -> (Int, Int) -> Maybe Board
putMark (Board board) player (x, y)
    | x < 0 || x > 2 || y < 0 || y > 2 = error $ "Invalid coordinates" ++ show (x, y)
    | board ! (x, y) /= Nothing = Nothing
    | otherwise = Just $ Board $ Map.insert (x, y) (Just player) board

emptySquares :: Board -> [(Int, Int)]
emptySquares (Board board) = [(x, y) | x <- [0..2], y <- [0..2], board ! (x, y) == Nothing]

instance Show Board where
    show (Board board) = 
        intercalate "\n- - - \n" 
            [ ( intercalate "|" [prettyShow $ board ! (x, y) | y <- [0..2]] ) 
                | x <- [0..2]]
            where
                prettyShow Nothing = " "
                prettyShow (Just X) = "X"
                prettyShow (Just O) = "O"

allX :: Board
allX = Board $ Map.fromList [((x, y), Just X) | x <- [0..2], y <- [0..2]]

allO :: Board
allO = Board $ Map.fromList [((x, y), Just O) | x <- [0..2], y <- [0..2]]
```

```hs
module Position where

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Maybe 
import Data.Map (Map)
import Data.List (minimumBy)
import qualified Data.Map as Map

import Board 

data Position = Position { curBoard :: Board, curPlayer :: Player }
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

type Line = [(Int, Int)]

winningLines :: [Line]
winningLines = [ [(x, y) | x <- [0..2]] | y <- [0..2]] ++ -- vertical lines
               [ [(x, y) | y <- [0..2]] | x <- [0..2]] ++ -- horizontal lines
               [[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)], -- main diagonal
                [(0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 0)]] -- off diagonal 

lineWinner :: Board -> Line -> Maybe Player
lineWinner b l
    | all (== Just X) marks = Just X
    | all (== Just O) marks = Just O
    | otherwise = Nothing 
    where 
       marks = map (getMark b) l 

boardWinner :: Board -> Maybe Player
boardWinner b = foldr (<|>) Nothing $ map (lineWinner b) winningLines

nextPlayer :: Player -> Player
nextPlayer X = O
nextPlayer O = X

succPositions :: Position -> [Position]
succPositions (Position b p) = newPosition . fromJust . markSquare <$> (emptySquares b)
    where
        newPosition b' = Position { curBoard = b', curPlayer = nextPlayer p }
        markSquare = putMark b p

isDraw :: Board -> Bool
isDraw b = null (emptySquares b) && isNothing (boardWinner b)

data Label = Win | Lose | Draw
    deriving (Show, Eq)
data Score = Score { label :: Label, height :: Int }
    deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Ord Score where
    (Score Win i) <= (Score Win j) = i >= j
    (Score Win _) <= _ = False
    (Score Lose i) <= (Score Lose j) = i <= j
    (Score Lose _) <= _  = True
    (Score Draw i) <= (Score Draw j) = i >= j
    (Score Draw _) <= (Score Win _) = True 
    (Score Draw _) <= (Score Lose _) = False

type KnowledgeBase = Map Position Score

scorePosition :: Position -> State KnowledgeBase Score
scorePosition pos@(Position b p)
    | isDraw b = pure $ Score { label = Draw, height = 0 }
    | (boardWinner b) == Just p = pure $ Score { label = Win, height = 0 }
    | Just _ <- (boardWinner b) = pure $ Score { label = Lose, height = 0 }
scorePosition pos@(Position b p) = 
    do
        knowledge <- gets (Map.lookup pos)
        case knowledge of
            Just s -> return s
            Nothing -> do
                let nextPositions = succPositions pos
                nextScores <- mapM scorePosition nextPositions
                let bestSuccScore = minimum nextScores
                let score = curScore bestSuccScore
                modify (Map.insert pos score)
                return score

bestResponse :: Position -> State KnowledgeBase Position
bestResponse pos@(Position b p) = 
    do
        let nextPositions = succPositions pos
        nextScores <- mapM scorePosition nextPositions
        let bestSucc = snd $ minimumBy (\(s1, p1) (s2, p2) -> compare s1 s2) $ zip nextScores nextPositions
        return bestSucc

-- given the minimum score among the successors,
-- compute the current score
curScore :: Score -> Score
curScore (Score Win i) = Score Lose (i + 1)
curScore (Score Lose i) = Score Win (i + 1)
curScore (Score Draw i) = Score Draw (i + 1)
```

```hs
module GlossUI where

import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Applicative
import Graphics.Gloss
import Graphics.Gloss.Interface.Pure.Game
import Debug.Trace

import Board
import Position

-- copying some code from https://gist.github.com/gallais/0d61677fe97aa01a12d5

data GameState = GameState {
      pos :: Position
    , kb :: KnowledgeBase
    , playersTurn :: Bool
    , needToEval :: Bool
    }
    deriving Show

type Size = Float

resize :: Size -> Path -> Path
resize k = fmap (\ (x, y) -> (x * k, y * k))

drawO :: Size -> (Int, Int) -> Picture
drawO k (i, j) =
  let x' = k * (fromIntegral j - 1)
      y' = k * (1 - fromIntegral i)
  in color (greyN 0.8) $ translate x' y' $ thickCircle (0.1 * k) (0.3 * k)

drawX :: Size -> (Int, Int) -> Picture
drawX k (i, j) =
  let x' = k * (fromIntegral j - 1)
      y' = k * (1 - fromIntegral i)
  in color black $ translate x' y' $ Pictures
     $ fmap (polygon . resize k)
     [ [ (-0.35, -0.25), (-0.25, -0.35), (0.35,0.25), (0.25, 0.35) ]
     , [ (0.35, -0.25), (0.25, -0.35), (-0.35,0.25), (-0.25, 0.35) ]
     ]

drawBoard :: Size -> Board -> Picture
drawBoard k b = Pictures $ grid : markPics where

  markPics = [drawAt (i, j) (getMark b (i, j)) | i <- [0..2], j <- [0..2]]

  drawAt :: (Int, Int) -> (Maybe Player) -> Picture
  drawAt (_, _) Nothing = Blank
  drawAt (i, j) (Just X) = drawX k (i, j)
  drawAt (i, j) (Just O) = drawO k (i, j)

  grid :: Picture
  grid = color black $ Pictures $ fmap (line . resize k)
       [ [(-1.5, -0.5), (1.5 , -0.5)]
       , [(-1.5, 0.5) , (1.5 , 0.5)]
       , [(-0.5, -1.5), (-0.5, 1.5)]
       , [(0.5 , -1.5), (0.5 , 1.5)]
       ]

checkCoordinateY :: Size -> Float -> Maybe Int
checkCoordinateY k f' =
  let f = f' / k
  in  2    <$ guard (-1.5 < f && f < -0.5)
  <|> 1    <$ guard (-0.5 < f && f < 0.5)
  <|> 0    <$ guard (0.5  < f && f < 1.5)

checkCoordinateX :: Size -> Float -> Maybe Int
checkCoordinateX k f' =
  let f = f' / k
  in  0    <$ guard (-1.5 < f && f < -0.5)
  <|> 1    <$ guard (-0.5 < f && f < 0.5)
  <|> 2    <$ guard (0.5  < f && f < 1.5)

getCoordinates :: Size -> (Float, Float) -> Maybe (Int, Int)
getCoordinates k (x, y) =
  (,) <$> checkCoordinateY k y <*> checkCoordinateX k x

gameUpdate' :: Size -> Event -> GameState -> GameState
gameUpdate' _ e gs
  | playersTurn gs == False || needToEval gs = gs
gameUpdate' k (EventKey (MouseButton LeftButton) Down _ (x', y')) gs =
    let newBoard = do 
            (i, j) <- getCoordinates k (x', y')
            putMark (curBoard $ pos gs) (curPlayer $ pos gs) (i, j)
    in case newBoard of
        Nothing -> gs
        Just b' -> gs { pos = Position { 
                              curBoard = b'
                            , curPlayer = nextPlayer (curPlayer $ pos gs) 
                            }
                      , playersTurn = False
                      , needToEval = True
                      }
gameUpdate' _ _ gs = gs

gameTime :: Float -> GameState -> GameState
-- let the player move
gameTime _ gs
  | playersTurn gs && not (needToEval gs) = gs
-- check if player has won
gameTime t gs
  | (needToEval gs) =
      case (boardWinner $ curBoard $ pos gs) of
        Just X -> gs { pos = (pos gs) { curBoard = allX } }
        Just O -> gs { pos = (pos gs) { curBoard = allO } }
        Nothing -> gs { needToEval = False }
-- make computers move
gameTime _ gs =
    let (pos', kb') = runState (bestResponse $ pos gs) (kb gs)
    in GameState {pos = pos', kb = kb', playersTurn = True, needToEval = True}

initGameState :: GameState
initGameState = 
  GameState {
      pos = Position {
        curBoard = initBoard
      , curPlayer = X
      }
    , kb = Map.empty
    , playersTurn = True
    , needToEval = False
    }

main :: IO ()
main =
  let window = InWindow "Tic Tac Toe" (300, 300) (10, 10)
      size   = 100.0
  in play 
        window 
        white 
        1 
        initGameState
        (\ gs -> drawBoard size $ curBoard $ pos gs) 
        (gameUpdate' size) 
        gameTime
```

I would like some feedback on the following:

- Is the best way to implement the `scorePosition` using the state monad? See [Line 63 in `Position.hs`]
- In general, is there a better way to implement the mechanism to pick the next move?
- Is there a better way to implement the main UI loop in `GlossUI.hs`? Or is the way of marking explicit points in the state space the best way?
- Is it a better idea to define the board in some other way in `Board.hs`?
- Anything else that is worth changing?

---

later edit: I made certain changes to my code. If you are curious, see [Link](https://javaplt.github.io/haskell-course/)

Comment: two small tips: gloss has scale, you can use it instead of resize; don't do two options guards, specially if you need to re-evaluate a expression, that's what ifs are meant for.

Comment: @pedrofuria what are options guards?

Comment: guards with two branchs

Answer (score 1):

For tic-tac-toe the efficiency of the scoring function doesn't matter much; you can do exhaustive search (as in your `scorePosition`) because the search space is very small.

Perhaps you could encode the positions as a product-of-sum type rather than a tuple of integers, which would eliminate a bunch of error checking:

```hs
data Coord = C1 | C2 | C3 deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Enum, Bounded)
type Pos = (Coord, Coord)
```

Re. code review : your Position and Board modules are very readable.

However for larger games (like chess) you need to prioritize the search schedule.